# Q: Update viewmodel property from a listview binded textbox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, properties, binding

i've got a textbox which text is binded to a listview selecteditem as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtAdditional" Width="300" Text="{Binding ElementName=lstPersons, Path=SelectedItem.Additional, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Now i like to implement a mechanism to add new items to the listview using this textbox to get the actual data. So i would like to bind the text of the textbox to a property of the viewmodel so it can be processed by a command.

So it the textboxes text has to be binded to the listviews selecteditem and additionally to a property of my viewmodel.

I've searched around and found some approaches but i can't help to think that there should be some simpler mechanism to archive this goal.

What I found by now:

1. Using MultiBindung with some kind of ValueConverter? So it seems to me that this is primary for displaying and not for updating a viewmodels property.
2. The use of some selfdefined custom control?
3. The use of an BindingProxy with in- and out-dependencyproperties like in [Impossible WPF Part 1: Binding Properties](https://www.shuzhiduo.com/A/QV5ZlA94zy/)?

Is there another, simpler solution to this or would i have to use one of those above?
And if one should use one of those approaches, which one whould you choose?

I can't help but thinking that this issue hasn't been given some thoughts already, using an mvvm pattern?! ;-)

Comment: You should add a property e.g., `SelectedPerson` to your view model. Use this property as the binding source for every control where required. For example bind it to `ListView.SelectedItem` and to `TextBox.Text`. You should always see the view model as the only data source and not some other control. Data always flows between control <--> view model, but "never" control <--> control. It makes things easier to think this way first.

Answer (score 0):

yes thanks to the hint from BionicCode.

We, or better I should have to think the MVVM concept out. Of course no - or at least as little code behind as possible.

I added the property "selectedPerson" to my viewmodel and bound the SelectedItem of the listview to this property. So the object related properties were at hand directly through the "selected" object in my viewmodel and there was no need anymore to access the textbox content at all.

Thanks to BionicCode for the hint!